# Why does "zu" come at the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure

I came across this sentence. Let's say there are two hats and someone is asking

> *Zu* welchem Hut passt meine Jacke?
>
> Which hat matches my jacket?

Why do we use *zu* here?

Normally we use *zu* to express "to/ at/ for". But here I can't understand the meaning of *zu*. Even if I omitted *zu*, the sentence would make sense to me. Then why should I use *zu*?

Comment: _"Even if we omit Zu , the satz will make sense"_ Nope, that would totally defeat the intended meaning.

Comment: ok @πάνταῥεῖ , then what is the meaning of zu in this satz

Comment: Please notice that in the German sentence, *Jacke* is the subject. In the English sentence, however, the subject is *hat*. So *zu* serves as marker as well (cf. the last paragraph of David Vogt's answer)

Comment: _Passen_ works more like the following construction: "to which hat does my jacket go well?"

Comment: I agree @phipsgabler

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In German, what number and type of objects a verb needs has to be learned. There are two relevant meanings of *passen* here, [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/passen) 1a and 1b.

The first states that a piece of clothing fits somebody with regard to size and cut. The piece of clothing is the subject, the person is a dative object (which is optional and can be left out).

> Seit meiner Diät passen **mir** (*dat.*) **meine Hosen** (*subj.*) wieder.

The plural of the verb *passen* shows that *meine Hosen* and not *mir* is the subject.

The second meaning of *passen* states that two things accord well, go together. One thing is the subject, the other a prepositional object introduced by *zu*. When introducing prepositional objects, prepositions are meaningless. In particular, *zu* does not have a directional meaning in this case.

> **Der Hut** (*subj.*) passt nicht **zur Jacke** (*prep. obj.*).

Note that this meaning is wider than the first and not limited to pieces of clothing and persons.

> **Die Verpflichtung des Schweden** passt **zur Strategie von YouTube**.

I don't know whether this is part of the confusion, but note that German word order is free in so far as (almost) any constituent can appear in first position in declarative sentences. This includes prepositional objects.

> **Zu dieser Jacke** passt der Hut nicht.
>   **Zu dieser Strategie** passt die Verpflichtung des Schweden.

Comment: Also if I interpret it as " to which hat my jacket suits" , it makes sense.. now i got it :)

Comment: Did you mean to write "size" rather than "seize"?